# I can not logout of guest session in mint 18.2.I have tried sudo but with no luck

Tags: logout

I accidently logged in to linux mint 18.2.I turned the computer on and before logging in as administrator I wiped the keyboard and started a guest session.Now I can not logout of  guest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to log out using GUI? Or have you tried reboot your computer and logging in as different user? If you still can't log out you might want to hard reboot your computer.